# The integral with respect to a probability on a compact Hausdorff space $K$ is a linear functional on $C(K)$ with norm $1$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

According to Diestel & Spalsbury in 'The Joys of Haar Measure', the integral with respect to a probability on a compact Hausdorff space is a norm $1$ functional on the set of continuous functions over $K$, $C(K)$, equipped with the supremum norm.

From a completely measure-theoretic standpoint, this makes sense since by properties of the Lebesgue integral and the fact that we have a probability $P$ as the underlying measure we have $\mid\int fdP\mid\leq\parallel f\parallel_{\infty}P(K)$, which implies that this functional should have norm at most $1$ on the subspace of continuous functions over $K$. On the other hand since the constant function $1$ is continuous and has integral equal to $1$, we should be able to conclude that equality holds.

Now, I started running into trouble when I saw the unusual way in which integration is defined in this book. The authors define the integral for $\mathcal{A}_{K}$-simple functions, where $\mathcal{A}_{K}$ is the algebra generated by $K$'s topology in the natural way and then claim that this functional extends continuously to the closure (with respect to the supremum norm) of the set of $\mathcal{A}_{K}$-simple functions. Let's say that is in fact true (and it should be). Then showing that this extended functional has norm $1$ should follow using the same argument. However, the authors took a completely different and more complicated path to show equality holds instead of simply taking the integral of $1\in C(K)$. Even worse, their proof assumes the measure is weakly regular, whereas the basic argument above doesn't.

Note: the book defines a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}_{K}$ to be weakly regular if for every $\epsilon>0$ $A\in\mathcal{A}_{K}$ there exist a closed set $F$ and an open set $U$ such that $F\subseteq A\subseteq U$ and $\mu(U\setminus F)<\epsilon$.

Am I missing something? I just don't see why the standard argument shouldn't work.

This is the proof the book gives:

[image: The result and its proof as stated in the book]

I should also mention that it's not clear to me at all why we should be able to partition $K$ in terms of elements of the algebra $\mathcal{A}_{K}$ and more importantly, why functions that separate sets should exist (as far as I know this doesn't hold in any compact Hausdorff space).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The argument based on taking the integral of 1 relies on the integral being positivity-preserving, i.e. that if $f \le g$ then $\int f \le \int g$.  Does this book actually prove that their integral has that property?

Comment: Another key distinction between this approach and Lebesgue is that here, the authors only assume that the measure is *finitely* additive.  In the Lebesgue theory, it has to be *countably* additive.  Now, I think it should follow from some version of the Riesz representation theorem that a finitely additive measure which is sufficiently regular must in fact be countably additive, but this is not trivial.

Comment: @NateEldredge They don't exactly prove it, but they claim positivity holds, which in turn implies monotonicity. In fact, they claim that the following inequalities hold: $\mid\int fd\mu\mid\leq\int\mid f\mid d\mu\leq\parallel f \parallel_{\infty}$. So, this operator has norm at most $1$. Then, since $1$ is an $\mathcal{A}_{K}$-simple function the definition given by the authors applies, yielding $\int 1d\mu=1$, which should imply that the norm is in fact $1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge On the other hand, I did notice that the authors only require the measure to be finitely additive, but how does that prevent me from claiming that by definition the integral of $1\in C(K)$ is $1$? I understand that not any finitely additive measure is a countably additive measure. From that perspective I understand why the authors add regularity conditions. What's weird is that they actively use this regularity to prove that that the norm of the operator is equal to $1$ which shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @NateEldredge Obviously, I must be overlooking something, because I find it extremely unlikely that the authors would present such a complicated proof in place of a more straightforward and general one unless it was necessary.